# SAS get groups with similar column content

Tags: sas

I am trying to get all the customers that have only purchased one kind of product out of my data.

E.g I have a data table here.

```
CustomerID  purchasedProduct
1            k
1            k
1            k
2            n
2            k
2            k
3            k
3            k
3            k
```

And I want to get all customers that only have purchased k product. In this example I like to get all data fra customerID 1 and 3 , because customerID 2 has purchased n product.
What should I do here?

Comment: I will sort the data by customerID and purchasedProduct.And then use nodupkey to get the last value of purchasedProduct: if k that means the customer has never purchased any other product then k. Then I can use his customersID to find his data fra original data table. BUt it takes a long process, any of you has better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PROC SQL` is ideal for this type of task... use a sub-query to get the customers purchasing a single product, then use that list to subset down the main dataset.

```
proc sql ;
  select *
  from maindata
  where CustomerID in(select CustomerID
                      from maindata
                      group by CustomerID
                      having count(distinct(PurchasedProduct)) = 1)
    and PurchasedProduct = 'k'
  ;
quit ;
```